# input geometry has unkown(0) geometry (Although st_transform is used)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 tables:

A table with 3 fields:

```
id (text)
geom (geometry)

select ST_SRID(geom)
from A
where geom is not null

result: 32636
```

B table with 2 fields:

```
name (text)
geom (geometry)

select ST_SRID(geom)
from B
where geom is not null

result: 0
```

A.geom contains polygons

B.geom contains points

I want to get all the distances between A.id, A.geom and B.geom.
I tried with:

```
select id, st_distance(a.geom, ST_Transform(b.geom, 32636)) as dist
from A as a, B as b
where a.geom is not null
group by id, a.geom, b.geom
order by dist desc
```

But I'm getting error:

```
"input geom has unkown(0) SRID"
```

How can it be if I'm using ST_Transform ?

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is talking about the SRID of the argument to `ST_Transform`, which is 0. The message means that the function has no idea in which coordinate system the point is, so it cannot transform it to another coordinate system.

[The documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_Transform.html) says:

> ST_Transform is often confused with [ST_SetSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_SetSRID.html). ST_Transform actually changes the coordinates of a geometry from one spatial reference system to another, while ST_SetSRID() simply changes the SRID identifier of the geometry.

That seems to be the case here.

You should probably use `ST_SetSRID` to interpret `b.geom` in SRID 32636.